# Graph theory: shortest path with vector weights

Tags: algorithm, theory, graph-theory

I have a strongly connected digraph with edges weighted with vectors, where each vector has only non-negative entries. I want to find a cycle such that the angle between the sum of the weights and a diagonal vector ([1, 1, 1, ... 1]) is minimized. Are there any algorithms out there for this sort of thing?

I'm fairly confident a Bellman-Ford type algorithm would give me a fairly good solution, but I'm not convinced that it will be the -best-...

Comment: "Angle between the vector and [1, 1, ..., 1] is minimised" sure is a weird way to specify an optimality criterion.  After a bit of algebra this is equivalent to "sum(x_i)^2/sum(x_i^2) is maximised", which seems more likely to lead to an algorithm.  (Though it still doesn't seem a natural fit for the usual graph search algorithms because adding an edge can inflate the denominator more than the numerator...)

Comment: Good point. I've been using this form, but not thinking about it that way. Upon further consideration, I could always rotate my reference frame, such that we minimize the projection onto any vector - say, [1, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0]. The price you pay is that now the vectors entries may be negative.

Thus we are left minimizing xi^2/sum(xi^2). Saves one summation, I suppose.

Comment: I'm feeling it might be time to abuse some inequalities for a 'good enough' approximation. Cauchy-Swarz to reduce the 2-norm calculation to 1norm, and triangle inequality to relate the sum of 1-norms...

Comment: Not familiar with Cauchy-Schwarz I'm afraid, but the rotation sounds like a good idea.  Although it will introduce negative vector elements, I don't *think* this will "make things worse" in any real sense, since the only advantage I can see to having only nonnegative elements would be if it guaranteed that the objective function value would never decrease as edges were added, and you don't have that property here.

Comment: Out of my own interest, how would you use these inequalities?  Would you somehow use them to bound out partial solutions (paths) based on simpler calculations, a la branch and bound?

Comment: The task is to find an x that maximizes f(x) = x0/2norm(x). While this is a scalar, we'll have to evaluate it addition of more vectors - f(x + dx). This can't be done exactly without saving every entry of x, and since most paths have different vectors, we'd have to save the vector for each path for each vertex.

However, if we're happy sacrificing some correctness and getting a 'good enough' solution, we could use the fact that 2norm(x + dx) <= k*1norm(x + dx) <= c*(1norm(x) + 1norm(dx)). Feels dirty, but would reduce our problem to optimizing g(x + dx) = (x0 + dx0)/(1norm(x) + 1norm(dx))

Comment: In this way, we could simply save a list of denominators and numerators at each vertex corresponding to each path - or, hopefully without affecting accuracy too much, just the best n, n << no. of paths to the vertex.

Comment: If you insist on a simple cycle, then even deciding whether it's possible to get the angle perfectly aligned is NP-hard, by reduction from Hamilton cycle. If it's possible to revisit arcs, then the problem is essentially continuous and there might be a way to compute a maximally aligned (fractional) circulation via convex programming.

Comment: I don't insist on a simple cycle, but I am looking for the solution to be a cycle. In a strongly connected component, the sum of edge weightings on a compound cycle is a linear combination of constituent simple cycles edge weighting sums is it not? I'm learning most of this graph theory on the fly - let me know if I've made a fundamental mistake somewhere. I'll look into some convex programming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arcs can be used multiple times, this problem can be formulated as a [quadratic program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_program). If the instance is not large, then it might be worthwhile to try one of the solvers that Wikipedia links to.

Let's take feasible solutions to be circulations x, i.e., positive linear combinations of simple cycles. Let A be the matrix representing the linear map from arcs to vectors. There's one trick, proved with a little algebra: instead of minimizing the angle of Ax relative to the all-ones vector, we minimize the length of Ax subject to the constraint that the dot product of Ax and the all-ones vector be 1.

Now we can write down the quadratic program.

```
minimize y1^2 + ... + yn^2 (positive semidefinite objective)
subject to
Ax - y = 0
x is a circulation
```

The last constraint breaks down as the linear constraints `x >= 0` and, for each vertex, that the sum of `x` values on arcs entering the vertex equals the sum of `x` values on arcs leaving.

Comment: Ah, good old quadratic programming. How did I do a maths degree and never come across this? Thanks, was most helpful. While I'm confident this would work, for those reading, I think I'll approach it a little differently. If we let M = [A | -d], where d is [1, 1, ..., 1]^T and y = [x^T, k]^T, then a perfectly aligned solution will satisfy M*y = 0. Alas, y >= 0 dictates this won't always have a solution, so instead we can minimize r.r, subject to M*y = r and y >= 0.

Comment: @DomJack Was it a pure maths degrees? Unlike the applied types, they tend to see a continuous function on a compact set and call it a day.

Comment: Negative, applied. I heard terms like 'graph theory' and 'analysis', but there was more of a modelling focus. Still super useful, don't get me wrong - I can actually grasp the basic concepts of most of the wikipedia pages I'm reading now - just leaves me up that well known creek when I don't even know what term to search for ;)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand the Bellman-Ford Algo it seems, that Dijkstra Shortest Path Algo does the same. But it's way faster couse of its greedy behaviour.

Edit: Dijkstra only works with non-negative entries. But that would fit your Problem

Comment: No it wouldn't. Even though all the entries of the vectors are positive, the angle between their sum can reduce with the addition of another. Consider the case of the [1, 0] and [0, 1] vectors.

Angle between ([0, 1] and [1, 1]) = pi/4
Angle between (([0, 1] + [1, 0]) and [1, 1]) = 0

Note the above example is obviously 2D, but I'd like to be able to generalize to N-D.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two cycles that share a common vertex. It's totally possible that there are positive integers p and q so that p times the vector for the first cycle added to q times the vector for the second cycle exactly equals a multiple of (1,1,...,1). Thus, unless you restrict to simple cycles, I don't think there is a fast algorithm for you that's provably optimal. Even if you restrict to simple cycles though, you could have part of a cycle equal to a vector x and the rest of the cycle equal to a vector c(1,1,...,1) - x, and you'd probably have no way to know this unless you enumerated all cycles and just check them. Thus I think brute force enumerating cycles may be the only feasible way to approach your problem if you want an optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried a brute force approach, but don't even know what to do with the results. I can find all simple cycles in the graph and sum the edge vectors involved (and since I can take an arbitrary number of trips around those cycles, the walks between cycles can be made negligible). The task then becomes:

For each cycle vector xi, find ai in N such that sum(ai*xi) = k*d, where d = [1,1,1,1]^T

Another way of looking at it would be to find the nullspace of [X, -d] [a k]^T, where X = [x0, x1, x2, x3, ... ] and a = [a0, a1, a2, ...]^T.

Comment: This in itself is fairly trivial (or at least, well covered in literature), but it still leaves me with lots of nullspace vectors (my particular problem has ~2.5m cycle vectors of length 16, resulting in 2.5m - 16 /approx 2.5m nullspace vectors). Unfortunately every one of those nullspace vectors has at least one negative value, meaning I'd need to find a linear combination of vectors that results in all positive values (any fractional rational values are fine, since we can scale the solution later).

Comment: There's always the simple brute force approach - try all combinations of all vectors - but this is prohibitively expensive - my best guess it's factorial in the number of cycles, which itself is exponential in the number of vertices. I don't fancy my chances of completing an O((e^N)!) ~ O(e^(N^2)) algorithm... so I thought I'd see what stackoverflow has to say :).

Comment: I understand what you're saying. What I'm saying is that there doesn't seem to be any structure in the problem that you can exploit, so brute force enumeration may be the best that you can do. I tried to give reasons why I think this may be the case, I may be wrong. I hope you get a positive answer.